# how to run a fuction on a mform button in php

Tags: php, moodle

I am new in PHP I am working on a project which uses moodle. I have created a mform button

```
  $mform->addElement('button', 'downloadCSV', 'Download CSV');
```

I want to download a CSV file on click of this button But how do I call a function when this button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

When adding a button to an mform, it gets an id of id_BUTTONNAME.  This means that in order to create a click event for it, you can define a function with that generated id in your .js file.  I generated a function for you here that should trigger every time your button is clicked, as long as it is pasted in a .js file that is included on your form:

```
$("#id_downloadCSV").click(function() {
    DO STUFF HERE
});
```